# mysql select rows based on more than one criteria and linked to another column

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I'm having some trouble working this one out... any suggestions would be very welcome.

I have a table such as the following:

```
collection_id    book_id    author
===================================  
    1             027       derek
    2             090       bob
    2             102       andy 
    2             102       bob
```

Now I want to retrieve the book_id for a book that I know belongs in collection 2 and is authored by andy AND bob (i.e. 102).

A query that includes a WHERE clause for andy AND bob returns nothing because obviously there is only one author per row. A query that includes a WHERE clause for andy OR bob returns the book_id for 090 and 102 because bob is the author of book 090 too.

How would you go about obtaining the right book_id for the book authored by andy AND bob?!

Many thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can only be solved using subqueries. For example, take a look at the [EXISTS keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

```
SELECT DISTINCT book_id FROM book_table b
    WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM book_table b2
            WHERE b2.book_id=b.book_id AND b2.author='andy')
        AND exists (SELECT 1 FROM book_table b3
            WHERE b3.book_id=b.book_id AND b3.author='bob')
        AND collection_id=2
```

or, simplified (but not symmetrical):

```
SELECT book_id FROM book_table b
    WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM book_table b2
            WHERE b2.book_id=b.book_id AND b2.author='andy')
        AND author='bob'
        AND collection_id=2
```

Alternatively, use `COUNT` in a subquery:

```
SELECT book_id FROM book_table b
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM book_table b2
            WHERE b2.book_id=b.book_id AND b2.author='andy') > 0
        AND author='bob'
        AND collection_id=2
```

Comment: Ah, the exists keyword... brilliant. My education continues...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the following:

SELECT `book_id` FROM `test_books` WHERE `collection_id`='2' AND `author` IN ('andy', 'bob') GROUP BY `book_id` HAVING count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from collection
where author = 'andy' and book_id in (
    Select book_id from collection where author = 'bob'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE author = 'andy') a
     (SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE author = 'bob') b
WHERE a.book_id = b.book_id
```

Comment: I added formatted, but I think you're missing a `,` between your two subqueries.